# customize src attribute in woocommerce single product image

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, single, lightbox

I need to add suffix to the end of image file name (in "href" attribute) that show when i click on the woocommerce single product image.

*: I'm using Enfold theme and is using magnific popup

frontend code :

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images" data-columns="4" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;">
<figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
    <a href="https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30.jpg" class="lightbox-added" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
        <img width="200" height="325" src="https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30.jpg" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single" alt="" srcset="https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30.jpg 200w, https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30-185x300.jpg 185w" sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px">
        <span class="image-overlay overlay-type-image" style="left: 0px; top: 5px; overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 325px; width: 210px;">
        <span class="image-overlay-inside"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div class="thumbnails"></div>
</figure>
```

I need to change

```
<a href="https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30.jpg" class="lightbox-added" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
```

to

```
<a href="https://azadiwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Golestan-MDF-30-fullsize.jpg" class="lightbox-added" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
```

Comment: What does the PHP that output's that look like?

Comment: I have been inserted the code below of "frontend code" title